# Spring MVC multi user application

Tags: spring-mvc, web, spring-security, multi-user

I am developing a web application using Spring MVC. Since I am kind of done with the the basic functionality, I was going to add user management. By this I mean that I have to extend the logic of the application to support several users. However being new to Spring MVC I am lost... How and where to add session management? How to change my controllers? Could anyone please suggest a good resourse? Tutorials which I find on the Internet mainly deal with page access by using Spring Security. I need more than that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ gives a good step by step direction on how to use spring security with a database based on user roles. I am not sure exactly what more you want that needs to be directly addressed in your question. The good thing with spring security is that you don't need to change your controllers. It uses a simple xml configuration and is independent of the platform you use.

Comment: ok. thanks. At least this tutorial helped me to get started )))